# I want to update my state values as soon as I am dispatching the actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Hi I am trying to get my state values as soon as I am updating it. But cannot achieve this

My initial state looks like this:

```
filterData: {year: "2021", programId: "America"}
```

I have a handleDelete function that is deleting the values from the object.

```
const handleDeleteChips = (e, value) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (chipData[0].year == value) {
      dispatch(updateFilterYear(''));      
    } else {
      dispatch(updateFilterProgramId(''));      
    }
}
```

I want as soon as I am disptaching, the state values should be changed to this:

```
filterData: {year: "", programId: "America"}
```

So, I have a idea that in react this doesn't happens just after setting the state. The component has to re-render so for this i have implemented useEffect.
In useEffect, to capture the value change and  I have done this :

```
useEffect(()=>{
  dispatch(updateFilterYear(filterData.year));
}, [filterData.year])
```

But it is still not working as expected. I am able to update the state values but not immediately. So is my code inside useEffect correct?

Comment: Why don't you put the value on the `useState` and update both the state with dispatch and with the set state function?

Comment: If you need better help you need to update the question and put all of your code so we understand what you're trying to achieve here, and then we would be able to help you

Comment: The values in the state *are* updated as soon as you call dispatch, and then your component gets notified by Redux that it should rerender, and it does rerender with the new values. Are you using useSelector? useState?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const handleDeleteChips = (e, value) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (chipData[0].year == value) {
      dispatch(updateFilterYear(''));   
      setFilterData: {...filterData,year: ""}
    } else {
      dispatch(updateFilterProgramId('')); 
      setFilterData: {...filterData, programId:""}
 
    }
}
```

Try this function ... Hope this solves your issue .